# Will "features" be overwritten when there is a distribution update?

Tags: commerce, distributions

Example scenario:

1. I create a site using commerce_kickstart 7x-2.0.
2. I modify some of the "Features"(ex. commerce_kickstart_user, commerce_kickstart_taxonomy) that are prepackaged with the distribution.

Question:

1. Will these "Features" be overwritten when an update comes, ex.
   commerce_kickstart 7x-2.1 (Not really sure if there is such as a
   thing as a distro update. Tried to google, went to issue queues,
   IRCs to no avail)
2. If the answer to #1 is yes,how do you maintain your configurations to the "features" when an update comes? Should they be renamed and moved to "/sites/all/modules/my_features"?

Comment: What do you mean by Features? Has it something to do with the features module?

Comment: A "feature" is a mini-module that can be obtained by using the "features" module. What I'm referring in the title are the mini-modules/features.

Comment: On an unrelated note, guide to updating Kickstart: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will be marked as overriden.
The [Features Override](http://drupal.org/project/features_override) was designed for this use case, so try it and report back.